# CiviCRM Dashboard not working (as reported by Karl Rudnick)

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I am waiting for the answer to [Karl Rudnick's question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/civicrm-dashboard-not-working-on-local-win-10-install-live-server-okay).  In my case I was on a clean new install of 4.7.12 and ran an automated upgrade of the "volunteer" extension.  The dashboard then shows the same as Rudnick's only with 4.7.12 as the version instead of 4.7.14.  After that I upgraded CiviCRM to version 4.7.14 hoping to solve the problem.  No luck.  I then disabled all CiviCRM extensions (volunteer, booking, and dependencies) since I was not using them.  That had no effect either.  Clicking on the "Configure Your Dashboard" has no effect.  All other functionality within CiviCRM still works and the dashboard was never important to me anyway but the future looks gloomy when something is all screwed up.

*The requested page "/welcome?prot=1&ver=4.7.12&uf=WordPress&sid=c4498a5126be0e5320b4c7260613feb0&lang=en_US&co=1228" could not be found.*

Comment: Hi Bob, welcome to StackExchange!  I've added a link to the question that I think you were referring to.  This will make it easier for people to understand your question.  Please check that I've linked to the correct question.

Comment: Is it hosted on a windows server?

Comment: It is hosted on a linux server, specifically Dreamhost.  It is a Wordpress website that is maintained at the current version.  I did a new build of CiviCRM 4.7.12 to add the CiviCRM extension to Wordpress and then substituted our database for the one that was built by the new install.  I then did an upgrade on the database to bring it to the current version.  Previously this database was running on AWS about a year or so ago.  After the upgrade everything checked out so I added the volunteer and bookings extensions.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has "gone away".  I have to assume that it was related to something in a cache somewhere, either in my browser or on the website.  I tried clearing both in the usual ways before, when there was a problem.  Now, two days after the last time I accessed the site it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Fwiw, my issue was cleared up by clearing both browser cache and cookies. The cookies were the key, I believe. At first I thought it was Windows (where it didn't work) vs linux (where it was fine), but the two browser cookies states were simply different.