# how to change civicrm settings from command line?

Tags: settings, cli

There are some common settings to change for dev sites at mycivi.localhost/civicrm/admin/setting/debug.  How can those be changed from the command line?

A better answer for the question [How should I copy a site from production to staging?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/how-should-i-copy-a-site-from-production-to-staging) would include this information I think.

I see on https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/staging-production/ that `$civicrm_setting['domain']['environment'] = 'Development';` can be placed in civicrm.settings.php, which I would expect would be sufficient(though it doesn't seem to affect what's displayed at /civicrm/admin/setting/debug)... but what about other settings like debugging and backtrace?

If I do `drush vget` I get a list of all kinds of Drupal settings that can be changed via `drush vset`.  Does CiviCRM have a comparable utility?  I tried `cv` and wondered if `cv vars:show` and `cv vars:fill` might be corresponding commands, but if they are I don't know how to use them to do anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use drush cv to update the settings in db.

eg `drush cvapi Setting.create environment="Production"`

You can find various options in API explorer to set other settings and see for command in cv and drush section.

[image]